# How do i explain to Xubuntu that some drive is actually internal?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive

I have two drives on my machine, both are internal. However, the second drive keeps showing up as external:

1. There is no trash facility on that drive. Files are deleted right away.
2. In all the file managers there is the 'Dismount' option, which then fails if i try to do that (since the drive's partition is mounted via fstab).

How can i explain to Xubuntu that the drive is actually internal, so that those things will get fixed?

Here's the line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/largevg-work    /home/volodya/work  ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   2
```

and also

```
$ udisksctl dump |grep '^[^ ]\|Remova'
[...]
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/MATSHITA_DVD_RAM_UJ8E1_SZD5L67522:
    MediaRemovable:             true
    Removable:                  true
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Multiple_Card__Reader_058F63666435:
    MediaRemovable:             true
    Removable:                  true
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST2000LM015_2E8174_ZDZ09HM4:
    MediaRemovable:             false
    Removable:                  false
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WDS250G1B0A_00H9H0_172703800034:
    MediaRemovable:             false
    Removable:                  false
```

My 'large' drive is showing false, as you can see. But still...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My tested solution (Caja,Thunar on Ubuntu 16.04/Linux Mint 18.2) is the mount option **x-gvfs-hide** in /etc/fstab to hide  partition:

```
/dev/mapper/largevg-work    /home/volodya/work  ext4    errors=remount-ro,x-gvfs-hide   0   2
```

Comment: Other possible solution could be to use [udev rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/416702/429130)

Comment: for some reason udev rules didn't work for me (probably my error), but this worked immediately and without any issues. it right away added trash to the mount point as well. everything is just as i wanted it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact that only your optical drive and your card reader are reported as removable and the entry `/dev/mapper/largevg-work` in your fstab, it looks to me like you are confusing a Logical Volume with a physical drive/partition. You might find [How do I check / modify LVM state on a pre-installed system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477/how-do-i-check-modify-lvm-state-on-a-pre-installed-system) useful, as well as comments 7 and 8 on [this bug report.](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7555) There's a good explanation of the differences between logical and physical volumes [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417642/logical-volume-physical-volume-and-volume-groups) Since an LVM is assembled from physical volumes and is a logical (virtualized) construct rather than a physical one, it can be changed (I.E. removable). Think of it like your optical drive or card reader in that while both of those devices have physical components, you can change the volume being accessed, hence they are considered removable.

Comment: based on the naming convention "large**vg**-work" I think you are on to something

Comment: So are you saying that there is something in LVM that causes this or that it's the fact that it is LVM to begin with that is causing it?

Comment: Expanded answer